# Sum nodes containing '$' character XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am programing a stylesheet in xslt 1.0 and have the following xml data:

```
<PurchasePrice>$100.00</PurchasePrice>
<Deposit>$560.00</Deposit>
<ChequeLine>
  <ChequeType>Bank</ChequeType>
  <ChequeAmount>$465.00</ChequeAmount>
</ChequeLine>
<ChequeLine>
  <ChequeType>Trust</ChequeType>
  <ChequePayee>Department of the Environment</ChequePayee>
  <ChequeAmount>$456.00</ChequeAmount>
</ChequeLine>
<ChequeLine>
  <ChequeType>Credit Union</ChequeType>
  <ChequePayee>Some Bank</ChequePayee>
  <ChequeAmount>$9,999,999.00</ChequeAmount>
</ChequeLine>
```

I need to calculate the total of all the **ChequeAmount**, **PurchasePrice** and **Deposit**.
I assume i have to use translate() to remove the **'$'** and possibly **number()** to convert it from a string.

Expected value would be: **10001580**

What would the approach be here? From what i understand, we can only set a variable once in XSLT, so i need to create some sort of counter function?

Should i do a for-each loop on the **ChequeLines**?
What would the best approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in XSLT 1.0 you'll have to use a tail-recursive mechanism to process one `ChequeLine` at a time, passing the running total from one to the next, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ChequeLine" mode="sum">
  <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::ChequeLine[1]" mode="sum">
    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + translate(ChequeAmount, '$,', '')"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ChequeLine[last()]" mode="sum">
  <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$sum + translate(ChequeAmount, '$,', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

To start the process off you'd do

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ChequeLine[1]" mode="sum">
  <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="translate(Deposit, '$,', '') + translate(PurchasePrice, '$,', '')"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I've used `mode="sum"` so these templates don't conflict with any other processing you're already doing on the `ChequeLine` elements.